# Building an add-on to hide a <div> block on an HTML page

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

There's a webpage with something annoying on it which I'd like to hide every time I visit it. I thought a good way to do this would be to make an add-on for Firefox.

I've never done this before, and came across the web-based Firefox add-on builder. I'm not too sure where to go from here though. I know it should be quite easy to do this though. I suppose all I need to do is check if a  block with a certain id is used on a website, and if it is, then delete/hide it from my view.

Is that the best way to do about this? If not, what do you suggest? If so, can you give me any tips to help me accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right, I got it:

Using just a standalone Firefox Add-On use the following code:

```
exports.main = function() {

    var pageMod = require("page-mod");
        pageMod.PageMod({
        include: "*.ca",
        contentScriptWhen: 'end',
        contentScript: 'document.getElementById("DIVID").style.visibility="hidden";'
    });
};
```

Just replace `DIVID` with whatever you want.

Similarly, in Greasemonkey, just add this to the script:

```
document.getElementById('DIVID').style.visibility='hidden';
```

The only reason I didn't want to use Greasemonkey is that it isn't as easy to share. But it's convenience can't be beat!

Answer (score 3):

1. Install the **latest FF**
2. Install the **latest AdBlock Plus**
3. Go to the website right click on specific element and then **Inspect Element(Q)**
4. Right bottom corner there is **Hide with ABP(AdBlock Plus)** button, click on it, then **Add Element Hiding Rule**

Comment: Updating this answer: Click on the AdBlock Plus icon on your toolbar > Block element > Click on element and confirm block. This will persist over page reloads (unlike RemoveAnything and others).

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) which is a very useful plugin for firefox. You can write your own script in JavaScript which operates on the page.

However, chances are that someone might have already written a script for the site in question that you can install from the http://userscripts.org/ repository.

Comment: Hi, that's great. But Greasemonkey is my last resort. I kind of wanted to try to make an add-on without it. Plus I want to try to code it myself just for the experience. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In well-formed HTML, any particular value for the `id` attribute should occur at most once in a document.  If your mission is to seek and destroy a recurring phenomenon, it might be labeled (if at all) with a `class`.  This is the case with Twitter's "promoted tweets", for example.

```
    var promotedTweets = document.getElementsByClassName("promoted-tweet");
    for (k=0; k<promotedTweets.length; k++) {
     promotedTweets[k].parentNode.removeChild(promotedTweets[k]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't [Adblock Plus](http://www.adblockplus.org) do the trick here? You can feed it an element hiding rule (based on the class or ID attribute) on any given website, if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I used the up-and-coming [`jpm`](https://github.com/mozilla/jpm) tool to write this, and incorporated the suggestions here. It is specifically for filtering certain `div` tags here on StackOverflow—how fitting. The code and the `xpi` add-on file is at [Github](https://github.com/fasiha/NonHot-StackOverflow).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative in Firefox is to create a userContent.css file and add css which hides the div.

See https://superuser.com/a/319322/ and note the comment which points out that "Starting with Firefox 69, you need to set the `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets preference` to `true`".